# How to extend ViewProps in Flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

Flow type complains about non-existent prop in ViewProps after upgrade. I am looking to extend ViewProps to allow the additional props for the sake of end-to-end testing.

I have a legacy codebase recently upgraded to the latest flow type version together with the react-native upgrade. Flow started complaining about some non-existent props used in `View`:

`Cannot create View element because property tabLabel is missing in ViewProps [1] but exists in props [2]`

The code looks like this:

```
<View tabLabel={{name: 'SOME_TAB_NAME', testID: 'TEST'}}> .. </View>
```

If I remove `tabLabel` I'll have to refactor the end-to-end test I have and the code base is huge. I'd rather not, but instead I'd like to do something like this:

```
declare module 'react-native' {
  declare type ViewProps = ViewProps & { tabLabel: {name: string; testID: string }}
}
```

At the moment, I added a suppress_type annotation to mute the error, but this is not great because I can't make sure that the rest of props in View are inputed correctly. All I want is to allow flow to pass for this specific prop, either by extending or by suppressing this narrow specific error.

Comment: The suppress_type annotation (e.g., `// $FlowFixMe`) only suppresses errors on the immediate next line. So, if you can write the code so that `tabLabel={...}` on its own line, then you can add the annotation directly above it and only ignore that specific error.

Comment: I have the supress_type set to $FlowFixMe, and it is what I used to suppress the error. I even tried to put it before the the prop tabLabel line (inside the <View open tag .. but it didn't work. It only suppresses when I put it before <View>.

Comment: My problem is that I need flow to notify me of any other legitimate type error that other props the same View has, so I don't want to suppress the whole View component for the sake of tabLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I found a way of doing this. It involves wrapping the `View` component that accepts a `tabLabel` property in addition to the standard `ViewProps` properties.

```
import React from "react";

// Should be imported from 'react-native';
type ViewProps = {| foo: string, bar: number |};

// Should be imported from 'react-native';
function View(props: ViewProps) {
  return "VIEW";
}

// Change `any` if you want to actually type check `tabLabel`
function MyView({ tabLabel, ...restProps }: {| tabLabel: any, ...ViewProps |}) {
  return <View {...restProps} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MyView // Error because of `baz` and not `tabLabel`!
      tabLabel={{ name: "name", testID: "testID" }}
      foo="string"
      bar="not number" // Error here, too!
      baz="not present"
    />
  );
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgeirgGUALCAVwBsATOAIyTlElhJO2XHADkRdDAC0AOxQxgANyRiKMAJ5heANWBIA7gAUcYAM5wAvHADeAHziYIEAFxwzMKMFkBzADTcKFBusswgPFBwdgC+FNS0jCwc3Lz80DBCjjh4EsQy8ooqauSYzLIYwBCycHqGABRgpmZutcZNAJS25HBwRDDMUNX4OgCSAKIA6mTk0ZQ0cADCDCi+vAAGKxprfJhwGixwBivwMBBwUsworKwacJracGgMSGgA1nBrMChcADLfSKw1iUyhUqnAALIaVp1Gx3b5-HisAIAOlRRA8Jgg5jg0Tc9jhv3+rDcmxRqNamOxMU6Nm6vSQ-UGcAAPK1bKjkeiYJSzNE4FQAHwUWbA8qKMEAQTAYDqNLpfQG1TqdJ6zMhbPmYygOEiPDQKGYZl4EF2ay4KAAXtsVpxZBB4J94US1gBCFU9AkIgGWGyw+QgJBufD+pD4AIZDwjAAiQYjMGj+Bxsw9HqcEEs+A8Xl8+HdPXNUAzdvgoXCSCgic12ugcGeRHDzjdKfzlqL9rgjSQRtkMFzKcFdPawqAA)

You can add any additional props to the type definition for `MyView`'s properties that do not appear in `ViewProps`. This should work with the actual `react-native` code but I haven't used the package so let me know if any problems arise. I actually think this solution is pretty clean compared to the alternatives of suppressing errors or modifying `react-native` types, but I do accept that having to define a wrapper component isn't ideal.